# Difference between a Vertx Context and a Kotlin Couroutine Context

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, vert.x, kotlinx.coroutines

Can someone please explain the differences and similarities between a Vertx Context and a Kotlin Couroutine Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Vertx context defines the concurrency of code execution in Vertx, it usually is associated to an event-loop (when it's a default context) and any asynchronous operation performed in Vertx when code is running in that context will guarantee that the callbacks will be performed in the same Vertx context. Such context is usually shared by many concurrent executions, for instance an HTTP server will share the same context for the concurrent HTTP requests it serves.

A Kotlin coroutine context is associated with a coroutine and plays a similar role but it is usually associated with a single flow of execution that is determined by the Kotlin coroutine construct such as `launch`. A Kotlin coroutine is usually in Vertx associated with a Vertx context so when the coroutine resumes, the Vertx context can be used to ensure that the Vertx concurrency model is respect